# Recording, saving and playing audio

Tags: javascript, audio, jquery, microphone

I'm about to embark on creating an app and would really appreciate some suggestions on what would be the best technology to use for my app's specific needs, which are listed below.

NEED:
-record and save an audio file via the microphone
-replay that audio file and re-record(record and save in place of the other)
-save several individual audio files and then play them together in a continuous loop, one after the other
BONUS:
-play separate audio file (background) simultaneously as the short audio clips are looping
-toggle background volume
-create and save a separate audio file with all tracks playing together

I'll mostly be using Angular and Javascript but would like to use a library or a plugin in for the audio functionality to make working with audio easier and faster. If you have any experience with things like Sound.js, Howler.js, or know of any others that could work, I'd love to hear your opinion.

Please also keep in mind that I am a relatively new programmer plus I have a tight time-frame for getting this up and running, so the easier to use the better! Thanks!